# xsl Variable or parameter is undefined but not in file

Tags: java, xslt

I'm stuck with an inherited xslt template, which produces an error:

```
line 200: Variable or parameter 'child' is undefined.
```

The problem is, there is no variable or parameter "child" in this line or any other in the whole file. The only reference to "child" is in xpath.
Line 200 looks like this:

```
  <xsl:with-param name="ancestor"><xsl:value-of select="$ancestor"/></xsl:with-param>
```

Here is the whole part that I think is relevant.

```
  <xsl:template name="create_title_row">
  <xsl:param name="ancestor"/>
  <xsl:param name="columnDepth"/>
  <xsl:param name="pos"/>
  <xsl:if test="$ancestor &lt; $columnDepth">
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/mask/table[position()=$pos]/descendant::clmn[count(ancestor::clmn) = $ancestor]">               
        <xsl:call-template name="create_column">         
          <xsl:with-param name="ancestor"><xsl:value-of select="$ancestor"/></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="columnDepth"><xsl:value-of select="$columnDepth"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    <xsl:call-template name="create_title_row">
      <xsl:with-param name="ancestor" select="$ancestor + 1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="columnDepth" select="$columnDepth"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos"/>

    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create_column">
  <xsl:param name="ancestor"/>
  <xsl:param name="columnDepth"/>

  <xsl:variable name="for_export"><xsl:value-of select="/mask/@for_export"/></xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="depth">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::clmn[not(child::clmn)]">
      <xsl:sort select="count(ancestor::clmn)"/>
      <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::clmn)"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="rowspan">
    <xsl:if test="$depth= ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="$columnDepth - $ancestor"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$depth!= ''">1</xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="abstand">     
    <xsl:if test="$ancestor!=0 or position()!=1">0</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$ancestor=0 and position()=1">1</xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="cs">
    <xsl:if test="$depth= ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="@colspan"/>                           
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$depth!= ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(descendant::clmn[not(child::clmn)]/@colspan)"/>         
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="colspan">
    <xsl:if test="$cs!=0">
      <xsl:value-of select="$cs + $abstand"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$cs=0">
      <xsl:value-of select="1 + $abstand"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>    

   <td class="column_title">
    <xsl:if test="$rowspan>'1'">
      <xsl:attribute name="rowspan"><xsl:value-of select="$rowspan"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$colspan>'1'">
        <xsl:attribute name="colspan"><xsl:value-of select="$colspan"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>


    <xsl:if test="$for_export='0'">
      <xsl:if test="string-length(@link)=0">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>         
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length(@link)!=0">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(@desc)!=0">
          <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>         

          <a class="mask_top" href="javascript:;" onclick="return(getOnlineHelp('{@link}'));" onmouseover="return(setzeStatus('{@desc}'));" onmouseout="return(setzeStatus(''));">
            <xsl:value-of select="@desc"/>
          </a>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="string-length(@desc)=0">
          <a class="mask_top" href="javascript:;" onclick="return(getOnlineHelp('{@link}'));" onmouseover="return(setzeStatus('{@title}'));" onmouseout="return(setzeStatus(''));">
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
          </a>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>        

    <xsl:if test="$for_export='1'">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>         
      <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </xsl:if>        
    <xsl:if test="string-length(@comment)!=0">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>         
      <sup><xsl:value-of select="@comment"/></sup>
    </xsl:if>
  </td>   
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: First thought, is that it might not be referring to line 200 in that file. Are there any xsl:import/xsl:include instructions that may refer to a different xsl file?

Comment: line 200 is outside the templates that you show, right? So, on the level of those templates (not inside), there must be a definition of the variable `ancestor`. Can you share it?

Comment: It's useful to say which XSLT processor you are using. You might find someone here familiar with its obscure error messages. You could also try running the stylesheet through a different processor to see if you get better diagnostics.

Comment: Line 200 is in fact in the part I included. There are no import/include instructions.

Comment: I don't know which processor is used. In fact the error only appears after a Birt report is generated, never before. It looks like a class loaded by Birt takes over.

Answer (score 1):

Now (2018) I am stuck at the same error. No imports, and the line is very similar. The line with the error was like this

```
<xsl:with-param name="ancestor" select="$ancestor"/>
```

I change the name of the variables to firstFather and error disappeared.

```
<xsl:with-param name="firstFather" select="$firstFather"/>
```

I think that ancestor is a reserved name and it fails when it is used in variables.